# SublimeText3 Build System for Pandoc

Tags: sublimetext3, pandoc

I am trying to create a build system to run pandoc and save as pdf using pdflatex:

```
{
"selector": "text.html.markdown",
"working_dir": "$file_path",

"cmd": [
    "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Pandoc",
    "-f", "markdown",
    "-t", "latex",
    "--pdf-engine=pdflatex",
    "-s",
    "-o",
    "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\output.pdf",
    "$file"
]
}
```

I get an "Access is denied" error and cannot figure out what's wrong:

```
[WinError 5] Access is denied
[cmd: ['C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Pandoc', '-f', 'markdown', '-t', 'latex', '--pdf-engine=pdflatex', '-s', '-o', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\output.pdf', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\CP10328R-TEST.md']]
[dir: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop]
```

I have confirmed that I can write a file to the desktop without any issues, so the "access is denied" error must be related to something other than the output file.  I have also tested using pdflatex as the engine and I can create PDFs from LaTex without any errors using an install of Texworks on the same machine, so the issue cannot be with LaTex.  Finally, I have confirmed the path to pandoc is correct.

Comment: Just to verify, if you run the same command as from the build from a command prompt, does it work there?

Comment: Thanks for the tip on trying it from the command line.  When I did that, the error message was "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Pandoc is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."  However, it is confirmed to be the right path.  Here it is copied directly from the file explorer: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Pandoc

Comment: In that case you perhaps need to add `\\pandoc.exe` or something similar to the first item in the `cmd` list; that item should be the program to execute for the build.

Comment: Adding .exe to the command line gave the same error.  And adding it to the cmd list in the build did as well, but slightly different - it said "The system cannot find the file specified".

Comment: Well to be clear, the first item in the `cmd` array needs to be the program to execute, which should include the full path as you've included above if the location isn't in your `PATH`. I'm not familiar with pandoc, but if that path is correct then there's some executable somewhere in there (maybe a `bin` directory or something?) that you need to use.

Comment: Got it!  Because the directory was already in the path, by simply removing the path it worked from the command line and from the sublime text build.  Problem solved!  Thank you.